# c# join XML files produce duplicates using Linq DefaultIfEmpty()

Tags: c#, xml, linq, join, duplicates

I'm trying to perfome a leftOuterJoin on two XML documents, however the way I am currently using seems to return some odd duplicate part from fileone (explain in the code below). I've tried many ways but couldn't figure out how to do this. Can someone please help to slove the problem? Many thanks in advance!

fileone:

```
<fileone>

    <Book BookID="dog"> Dog </Book>

    <Book BookID="cat"> Cat </Book>

</fileone>
```

filetwo:

```
<filetwo>

       <Edition BID="cat" OrderID="100"> about cat</Edition>

       <Edition BID="cat" OrderID="200">more about cat</Edition>

</RightSeq>
```

what I'm looking for is(left outer join on bookID=BID):

```
<item>
   <Book BookID="cat"> Dog </Book>
</item>
<item>
    <Book BookID="cat"> Cat </Book>
    <Edition BID="cat" OrderID="100"> about cat</Edition>
</item>
<item>
    <Book BookID="cat"> Cat </Book>
    <Edition BID="cat" OrderID="200"> more cat</Edition>
</item>
```

My (wrong) code:

```
      var result = from a in fileone.Descendants()
      join b in secondxdoc.Descendants()
     on (string)a.Attribute("BookID") equal (string)b.Attribute("BID") into inners
      from ele in inners.DefaultIfEmpty()

      select new XElement("item", new XElement(a), ele == null ? null : new XElement(ele));
        var output = new XElement("LeftOuterJoin", result);         
    }
```

Currently wrong result:

```
<item>
   <fileone>  
       <Book BookID="dog"> Dog </Book> // this entire <fileone> bit is unwanted
       <Book BookID="cat"> Cat </Book>  //I don't know what I've done wrong
   </fileone> 
</item>
    <item>
   <Book BookID="cat"> Dog </Book>
</item>
<item>
    <Book BookID="cat"> Cat </Book>
    <Edition BID="cat" OrderID="100"> about cat</Edition>
</item>
<item>
    <Book BookID="cat"> Cat </Book>
    <Edition BID="cat" OrderID="200"> more cat</Edition>
</item>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unwanted first `<item>` element was the result of joining the root element `<fileone>` with descendants of the 2nd file. If you want to skip the root element, replace `fileone.Descendants()` with `fileone.Root.Descendants()` :

```
var result = from a in fileone.Root.Descendants()
             join b in secondxdoc.Descendants()
                on (string)a.Attribute("BookID") equal (string)b.Attribute("BID") into inners
             from ele in inners.DefaultIfEmpty()
             select new XElement("item", a, ele);
var output = new XElement("LeftOuterJoin", result);
```

**<kbd>[`Dotnetfiddle Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Jse4se)</kbd>**

Answer (score 0):

I got results without using traditional linq.  The join will not give results where fileone doesn't have a matching item in filetwo.

```css
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input1 =
               "<fileone>" +
                   "<Book BookID=\"dog\"> Dog </Book>" +
                   "<Book BookID=\"cat\"> Cat </Book>" +
               "</fileone>";
            XDocument fileone = XDocument.Parse(input1);

            string input2 =
               "<filetwo>" +
                      "<Edition BID=\"cat\" OrderID=\"100\"> about cat</Edition>" +
                      "<Edition BID=\"cat\" OrderID=\"200\">more about cat</Edition>" +
               "</filetwo>";
            XDocument secondxdoc = XDocument.Parse(input2);

            //<item>
            //   <Book BookID="cat"> Dog </Book>
            //</item>
            //<item>
            //    <Book BookID="cat"> Cat </Book>
            //    <Edition BID="cat" OrderID="100"> about cat</Edition>
            //</item>
            //<item>
            //    <Book BookID="cat"> Cat </Book>
            //    <Edition BID="cat" OrderID="200"> more cat</Edition>
            //</item>
            XElement output = new XElement("Root");
            foreach (XElement item in fileone.Descendants("Book"))
            {
                string bookId = item.Attribute("BookID").Value;
                List<XElement> bookTwoItems = secondxdoc.Descendants("Edition").Where(x => x.Attribute("BID").Value == bookId).ToList();
                if (bookTwoItems.Count  == 0)
                {
                    XElement newItem = new XElement("item");
                    output.Add(newItem);
                    newItem.Add(item);
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (XElement bookTwoItem in bookTwoItems)
                    {
                        XElement newItem = new XElement("item");
                        output.Add(newItem);
                        newItem.Add(item);
                        newItem.Add(bookTwoItem);
                    }
                }
                
            }
        
        }
    }
}
​
```

Got it to work with Left Outer Join

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input1 =
               "<fileone>" +
                   "<Book BookID=\"dog\"> Dog </Book>" +
                   "<Book BookID=\"cat\"> Cat </Book>" +
               "</fileone>";
            XDocument fileone = XDocument.Parse(input1);

            string input2 =
               "<filetwo>" +
                      "<Edition BID=\"cat\" OrderID=\"100\"> about cat</Edition>" +
                      "<Edition BID=\"cat\" OrderID=\"200\">more about cat</Edition>" +
               "</filetwo>";
            XDocument secondxdoc = XDocument.Parse(input2);

            //<item>
            //   <Book BookID="cat"> Dog </Book>
            //</item>
            //<item>
            //    <Book BookID="cat"> Cat </Book>
            //    <Edition BID="cat" OrderID="100"> about cat</Edition>
            //</item>
            //<item>
            //    <Book BookID="cat"> Cat </Book>
            //    <Edition BID="cat" OrderID="200"> more cat</Edition>
            //</item>
            var results = (from one in fileone.Descendants("Book")
                           join two in secondxdoc.Descendants("Edition") on one.Attribute("BookID").Value equals two.Attribute("BID").Value into inners
                           from two in inners.DefaultIfEmpty()
                           select new { fileone = one, filetwo = two == null ? null : two }).ToList(); 
            XElement output = new XElement("Root");
            foreach (var item in results)
            {
                XElement newItem = new XElement("item");
                output.Add(newItem);
                newItem.Add(item.fileone);
                if (item.filetwo  != null)
                {
                        newItem.Add(item.filetwo);
                }

            }

        }
    }
}
​
```

Or this method

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input1 =
               "<fileone>" +
                   "<Book BookID=\"dog\"> Dog </Book>" +
                   "<Book BookID=\"cat\"> Cat </Book>" +
               "</fileone>";
            XDocument fileone = XDocument.Parse(input1);

            string input2 =
               "<filetwo>" +
                      "<Edition BID=\"cat\" OrderID=\"100\"> about cat</Edition>" +
                      "<Edition BID=\"cat\" OrderID=\"200\">more about cat</Edition>" +
               "</filetwo>";
            XDocument secondxdoc = XDocument.Parse(input2);

            //<item>
            //   <Book BookID="cat"> Dog </Book>
            //</item>
            //<item>
            //    <Book BookID="cat"> Cat </Book>
            //    <Edition BID="cat" OrderID="100"> about cat</Edition>
            //</item>
            //<item>
            //    <Book BookID="cat"> Cat </Book>
            //    <Edition BID="cat" OrderID="200"> more cat</Edition>
            //</item>
            XElement output = new XElement("Root");
            var results = (from one in fileone.Descendants("Book")
                           join two in secondxdoc.Descendants("Edition") on one.Attribute("BookID").Value equals two.Attribute("BID").Value into inners
                           from two in inners.DefaultIfEmpty()
                           select new { fileone = one, filetwo = two == null ? null : two })
                           .Select(x => x.filetwo == null ? new XElement("item", x.fileone) : new XElement("item", new object[] { x.fileone, x.filetwo }));
            foreach (var item in results)
            {
                output.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }
}
​
```